# Iterate Through Each Record

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I have an ASP.NET page which repeatedly calls a SQL stored procedure that pulls a random userID from the table Hearings_Users. What I need now is to pull each UserID in successive order.  I would go down the list of UserIDs in the table until the VB function stopped calling it.  I'm not sure how to do this in SQL. Thanks

```
Private Function GetRandomUser() As String
    Dim UserID As String = ""
    cmd = New SqlCommand("p_Hearings_ActiveUsers", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    ....
        While dr.Read()
                UserID = dr("UserID")
            End While
        End Using   
    ....     
    Return UserID
End Function

--p_Hearings_ActiveUsers
SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM Hearings_Users
WHERE Active = 1
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Unless you've got an absurd number of users (millions?), I would load this into a DataTable and then iterate in VB. It will be faster and less taxing than querying the database on each row and paginating server-side.

Comment: If you need to do this in a certain order I would strongly consider rethinking the process. Don't call a procedure over and over and over just to get the next value. Instead call a procedure one time that returns all the values you are going to need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a new stored procedure that takes a parameter of the last userID, and returns the next in sequence

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spNextUser(@LastUserID INT)
```

The body would be like p_Hearings_ActiveUsers except it has a condition that the ID is greater than the last used

```
SELECT TOP 1 UserID 
FROM Hearings_Users
WHERE Active = 1 
    AND UserID > @LastUserID
ORDER BY UserID
```

When you call this from code, you'll need to add a parameter to the command

```
Dim paramUserID As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("LastUserID", SqlDbType.Integer)
paramUserID.Value = dr(UserID)
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUserID)
```

but it's otherwise just like the call you have already

This approach insures the state is stored in your application, not server side, so if 2 instances are iterating through they don't cross each other up

Efficiency tip: You don't need to redefine the parameter each loop iteration, you can define it above the loop and inside the loop just update it's value.

Comment: Oh, I like that a lot. Not too complicated and uses what I mostly have. Thanks very much.